# move the result of select2 to the other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I am using `select2` and I use it for a single choice. I want to move the result of what we have chosen to another div.

Please check my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/hxe7wr65/

How to move it? because I don't want the result to show in the box. I want the box still clear and even after I choose, the placeholder still shows up.

This is the design that i'm doing right now

[image]

in that image. its only can choose 1 option. after we choose. the result show up to another place and so the select still have the placeholder in it. please guys help me.
thank so much

Comment: someone?? please help

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm not 100% sure this is what you're looking for, but I think you wan't the grab value of the last selected item, transfer it to another div and then clear the input. 
For the first step add an event handler to it.

```
var $eventSelect = $("#position"); //select your select2 input

$eventSelect.on('select2:select', function(e) {
    console.log('select')
    console.log(e.params.data.id) //This will give you the id of the selected attribute
    console.log(e.params.data.text) //This will give you the text of the selected text
})
```

Now that you have the value, transferring it to the other div is relatively simple.

```
var $eventSelect = $("#position"); //select your select2 input

$eventSelect.on('select2:select', function(e) {
    var text = e.params.data.text
    $("#otherdiv").append(text)
})
```

Then to clear the form

```
var $eventSelect = $("#position"); //select your select2 input

$eventSelect.on('select2:select', function(e) {
    var text = e.params.data.text
    $("#otherdiv").append(text)
    $(this).val('');
    // or depending no what version you are using
    $(this).select2('val', '')
})
```